# Table View not populating objects

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GenusNameCell";

    GenusNameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[GenusNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GenusNameCell"];


        cell.GenusNameLabel.text = [genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

I have a tableview with an Array of objects but when I run it. Nothing shows up. Im fairly new to xcode but Im not sure what my mistake is in the code. Can some one help me out?

Comment: Did you initialized your array `genusName` ?

Comment: GenusNameCell: From xib?

Comment: Code looks good.  Data must be bad.  Please verify.

Comment: Yea I did genusName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [genusName addObject:@"Abies"];

Comment: Where did you do that?

Comment: In my rootviewcontroller in the viewdidload

Answer (score 1):

If the cellForRowAtIndexPath callback is never called, it could be:

- you didn't have set the dataSource of your tableview;
- you didn't implement the numberOfSectionsInTableView: and/or tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: callbacks.

And if you dequeue your cell, you need to set the text outside the if branch like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GenusNameCell";

    GenusNameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[GenusNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GenusNameCell"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    cell.GenusNameLabel.text = [genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this your code will run,

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GenusNameCell";

GenusNameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[GenusNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GenusNameCell"];

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

}
cell.GenusNameLabel.text = [[genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] geniusname];

return cell;
}
```

`geniusname` is the NSString you stored the name of the person.

Comment: That doesn't do it either

Comment: how could you save your string on the array,.. can you share your code please

Comment: Actually, you add all your data to a genusName array,.. Then only you can retrieve from it,..